# Replaceitem not working on Bedrock

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

For some reason, if I try using `/replaceitem` it won't execute the command inside of a command block. This is the command I used:

```
/replaceitem block -10 -58 -27 slot.container 1 ender_pearl 1
```

Comment: I've just tested the exact command with a chest in the exact same spot and it works perfectly fine. Are you sure your container is in the location specified? What container are you using?